# Volume form of $I\times N$ in term of $\mathsf{Vol}_N$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

This is an Exercise of P. Petersen's Riemannian Geometry.

> Prove that the volume form for a metric $g=dr+\rho^2(r)g_N$ on a product manifold $I\times N$ is given by $\rho^{n-1}dr\wedge \mathsf{Vol}_N$. (Presumably $n=\dim(N)$.)

Petersen definition of volume form is as follow:
$$\mathsf{Vol}(e_1,\dots,e_n)=\det[ g(e_i,e_j) ].$$
and for ONB and a general vector field $X$ $$\mathsf{Vol}(e_1,\dots,X,\dots,e_n)=g(X,e_j).$$

[image]

Now using this, and orthonormal frame $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ for $(g_N,N)$ we have
$$\mathsf{Vol}_{I\times N}(e_1,\dots,e_n,\partial_r)=\det\begin{bmatrix}\rho^2&0&\dots&0&0\\0&\rho^2&\dots&0&0\\0&0&\dots&\rho^2&0\\0&0&\dots&0&1\\\end{bmatrix}=\rho^{2n}$$
and we know that $\mathsf{Vol}_{I\times N}=kdr\wedge \mathsf{Vol}_N$ so $k=\rho^{2n}$ but this do not coincide with the suggested in the question.

Comment: Consider the example of a spherical shell where $N=S^2$ and $\rho = r$.

Comment: @AHusain: My solution is wrong?

Comment: Aren't you missing some square root in the definition of the volume? What you wrote is $2n$-homogeneous (i.e $Vol(\lambda e_1,\ldots, \lambda e_n) = \lambda^{2n} Vol(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and cannot be a $n$ form. Also, either $N$ is $n-1$ dimensional and then the cited formula is right, either $N$ is $n$ dimensional and then the formula should be $\rho^n dr \wedge dvol_N$.

Comment: @Didier: In Petersen book there is no square root. Also no comment on what $n$ is.

Comment: @C.F.G There might be typos then. In polar coordinates in $\Bbb R^n$, the volume form is given by $r^{n-1} dr \wedge dVol_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}$. In Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine's book, this is made in section 3.H.2

Comment: @Didier: Tnx, I'll check Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine's book. So my solution is almost correct?

Comment: Well, replacing $\rho^2$ with $\rho$ and $n$ with $n-1$, this is OK. I guess do Carmo means that $I\times N$ has dimension $n$, so that $N$ has dimension $n-1$

Comment: @Didier: You meant Petersen? I've added a screenshot of Petersen definition. take a look.

Comment: @C.F.G Of course I meant Petersen! Sorry about that

Comment: The exercise itself has a typo in it. The metric is $dr^2 + \rho^2 g_N$ (remember that the metric is a 2-tensor). One multiplies the length of a tangent vector to $N$ by $\rho$, not by $\rho^2$. And, no, $n$ is the dimension of the product manifold.  Be warned; my experience with Petersen's book was that it was filled with little annoying bits of sloppiness — but when I complained to him, he commented that anyone smart enough to read his book was smart enough to sort all those annoying bits out.

Comment: @TedShifrin: that is my mistake. Thanks for comment. Now I know that I have to be  a bit careful.